# Sequelize Model exports a Function

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i have define this model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require("../database/db")
var Reparacion = db.sequelize.define('reparaciones', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    descripcion: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    fecha_inicio: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
    fecha_fin: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
  },{});
module.exports=Reparacion
```

In other model when I define the foreing Key in other model, the methods HasMany and belongsTo doesn't works because I call them on a function:

```
  const Reparacion = require("./reparacion")
  console.log(typeof(Vehiculo))
  console.log(typeof(Reparacion))
  Vehiculo.hasMany(Reparacion,{foreingKey:"vehiculoId", onDelete: 'cascade', sourceKey:"matricula"})
  Reparacion.belongsTo(Vehiculo)
```

The both console log return: "function"

What i have to change for define correctly the association??

**EDIT**

that is de "Vehiculo" model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require("../database/db")
var Vehiculo = db.sequelize.define('vehiculos', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: true
    },
    matricula: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    marca: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    },
    modelo: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    },
    
    anio: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    color: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
      allowNull: true
    },
    puertas: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    motor: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
      allowNull: true
    },
  },{});
  const Reparacion = require("./reparacion")
  Vehiculo.hasMany(Reparacion,{foreingKey:"vehiculoMatricula", onDelete: 'cascade', sourceKey:"matricula"})
  Reparacion.belongsTo(Vehiculo)
  module.exports=Vehiculo
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is expected that `typeof Vehiculo` and `typeof Reparacion` will return a `function` that happens because every constructor or class is a function in JS, so when you create a model for an entity it returns a function/constructor that can create an instance of an entity for you. So there is no problem with that.

And actually the documentation shows similar code https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

Comment: But if y call the function i got an error:  "TypeError: Vehiculo.hasMany is not a function"

Comment: Could you add how you export and import `Vehiculo` ?

Comment: that code generate a table called "vehiculoId" VARCHAR(45), but i dont know why this name, and why isnt foreing key